# Worker thread issue with postMessage()

Tags: nativescript

In the worker thread, when I call postMessage() to send message back to the main thread - it's not allowing a single argument signature.

e.g. postMessage( { success: true } );

VisualCode is displaying a required signature of postMessage(any, string, transfer? );

I've got require('globals'); at the top of the worker file.

This is what I have so far:

```html
require('globals'); // necessary to bootstrap tns modules on the new thread

onmessage = function(msg)
{
    var request = msg.data;
    var data = request.data;
    var result = "OK";

    var message : any = result !== undefined ? { success: true, src: result } : { };

    postMessage( message ); // << problem
}
```

Comment: What worker thread implementation are you using? What version of NativeScript?

Comment: NS 2.4.1 and TS 1.8.10

Answer (score 2):

It's a little workaround, however I managed to fix it in my app by adding re-declared function signature in the beggining of the worker file like this:

```
declare function postMessage(message: any);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to mention that the error you are seeing is most likely a compilation error as a result of using TypeScript.

The nativescript workers implementation should only take one argument as of the current version.

Add reference to `node_modules/tns_core_modules/webworker.es2016.d.ts` as they contain the proper definition

Comment: Oops..spoke too soon. I added the reference to references.d.ts and the Visual Code/ts error went away. But when I try to compile I get DUPLICATE Worker error. I'm using TS 1.8.10.  Do I need to use TS 2.0+. These es2016 definitions seem to require that.

Comment: The conflict seems to be with 'node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts(16138,11): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Worker'.'